# POST Variables on a FORM PHP

Tags: php

I'm posting variables from my form on to another form, all the variables that are being posted on an `INPUT` field are showing fine. When a variable is needed to post on a `SELECT` how can I do this?

I tried within the `<SELECT>` tags to use `value="<?php echo $myvariable; ?>"` but this returns a blank.

Comment: You must add selected="selected" to the correct option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the selected option within a `<select>` tag, use the `selected` attribute. In this example, "Value 3" is selected:

```
<select name="myvariable">
  <option value="1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="3" selected>Value 3</option>
</select>
```

We can use PHP with something like this:

```
<select name="myvariable">
  <option value="1" <?php echo ($myvariable == '1' ? 'selected' : '')?>>Value 1</option>
  <option value="2" <?php echo ($myvariable == '2' ? 'selected' : '')?>>Value 2</option>
  <option value="3" <?php echo ($myvariable == '3' ? 'selected' : '')?>>Value 3</option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps :) x

Comment: Thanks @emily I tried your way and still I get nothing returned

Comment: What do you mean 'nothing returned'? You mean the first select option is always selected? Where is `$myvariable` set?

Comment: My mistake I had the option values set as a letter and not a number as was in my database. Fixed now works a treat :-) thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks, it's my first big project in web development, previously just done bits and bobs pulling tables of data back and charting. I'm building a whole app and learning every day :-)

Comment: I was thinking, if I have the `SELECT` fed by the database, would what  you posted above work also. This below is the PHP database feed`<label>Fuel Type</label>
<?php $fueltype = db::getInstance()->query('SELECT * FROM lkup_fueltype');
if(!$fueltype->count()) {
echo 'Problem';
} else { ?>
<select tabindex="1" id="propertyfueltype" name="propertyfueltype">
<?php foreach ($fueltype->results() as $fueltype) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $fueltype->PropertyFuelType; ?>"><?php echo $fueltype->PropertyFuelType; ?></option>
<?php }
} ?>
</select>`

Answer (score 0):

Your usage is incorrect. Check select documentation [over here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select).

Example usage

```
    <!-- The second value will be selected initially -->
<select name="select">
    <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
    <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
    <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

So for your case you should say

```
<select name="select">
    <option value="value1"><?php echo $myvariable;  ?></option> 
</select>
```